# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts/taglib/html/FormTag

Tags: struts, struts-1

I have a Java EE application that uses Struts. It mostly works correctly, but suddenly I'm getting an exception.

I have the Struts jar file in WEB-INF/lib and earlier the application was running normally.

The exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts/taglib/html/FormTag
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:865)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
org.apache.jsp.Fichier_jsp._jspService(Fichier_jsp.java:88)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: Try to remove the jar file from the classpath and add it again. If it isn't already on the classpath, add it.

Comment: i do it, and i have this error : org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find ActionMappings or ActionFormBeans collection
 help me please

Comment: You're missing a library or dependency, or have mixed versions of your libraries.

Comment: you can always open your JAR and check if the class is inside, you may have guessed wrong and actually it is not there

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing this dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
   <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using Maven, you will have to download it.